# C++ function return problem with defined variable

Tags: c++, function, variables, return

here is the problem: I have this function named func3 that uses three inputs and should return a calculation based on them. however, I cannot manage to return the calculated value from the function.
this is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
/*
bool func1(int budget){
    if( budget < 0 ) {
        cout << "Budget cannot be negative."<< endl; 
        return false; 
    }
    else {
        return true; 
    }
}
bool func2(int num1, int num2, int num3){ 
    if (int num1 < 0 || int num2 < 0 || int num3 < 0 ) {
        cout << "All quantities must be positive."<< endl;
        return false;
    }
    else { 
        return true;
    }
}
*/
int func3(int *p){
    
    int currentprice = *(p+0) * 5 + *(p+1) * 10 + *(p+2) * 15  ;
    cout << currentprice; cout << endl;
    return  currentprice; 

}









int main() {
    /*
    int budget;
    int num1, num2, num3;
    */
    int p1;
    int p2;
    int p3;
    int currentprice= 0;
    cin >> p1 >> p2 >> p3 ;
    int position[3] ;
    int *p;
    p= position;
    *(p+0) = p1 ; 
    *(p+1) = p2 ; 
    *(p+2) = p3 ;
    func3(p);
    cout << *(p+0) << endl;
    cout << currentprice << endl;
return 0; 
}
```

and consol is :

1

1

1

30

1

0

Press any key to continue . . .

where is first three 1 is input others are output.
the problem can be detected with 30 and 0 outcomes they should be the same for me but I cannot return currentprice value from the function.

Comment: It's entirely unclear what your problem is.

Comment: @JosephLarson u are right maybe. here is the problem: I have this function that uses three input and should return a calculation based on them. however, I cannot manage to return the calculated value from the function.

Comment: Okay, but what is input you're testing with, what should the result be, and what are you really getting? What is the calculation doing? Your code is a very very strange style, so it's really quite difficult to tell what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Where does it get returned to?

Comment: @ where is first three 1 are input others are output. the problem can be detected with 30 and 0 outcomes they should be the same for me but I cannot return currentprice value from the function.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb to the end of main just before couts.

Comment: Hint: you are discarding the return value of func3(). It never makes it back to main().

Comment: @StephenM.Webb Thank you for your hint. How can I hold its value after the func3() ? can you please help me ?

Comment: replace `func3(p);` --> `currentprice = func3(p);`

Comment: @Eugene thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You do some really strange things. This isn't going to be an answer, but it's going to address some of your weird code.

```
int position[3] ;
int *p;
p= position;
*(p+0) = p1 ; 
*(p+1) = p2 ; 
*(p+2) = p3 ;
```

Okay that's just gross. I had to look at it for a while, but I think this makes more sense:

```
p[0] = p1;
p[1] = p2;
p[2] = p3;
```

Of course your use of cryptic variable names means I have absolutely zero idea what this data is supposed to be.

```
int currentprice = *(p+0) * 5 + *(p+1) * 10 + *(p+2) * 15  ;
```

Again, just as cryptic. I think you mean:

```
int currentPrice = p[0] * 5 + p[1] * 10 + p[2] * 15;
```

Of course, I have absolutely no idea what this calculation is supposed to be. But this is the way people will expect you to handle arrays. Dereferencing pointers is just going to confuse people.